# Did the early generations do melacha on Chol Ha'moed?

Tags: halacha, history, halacha-theory, chol-hamoed, drush

The [Gemara in Chagiga](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.18a.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) says:
that the Torah left it up to Chazal to figure out what constitutes as "work" on Chol Ha'moed.

> "הא לא מסרן הכתוב אלא לחכמים, לומר לך אי זה יום אסור ואי זה יום מותר,
> אי זו מלאכה אסורה ואי זו מלאכה מותרת"

I am assuming (see below for my reason) that there were many generations BEFORE the Chachomim actually made that decision. What did those earlier generations do on Chol Ha'moed?

Reason for my assumption: I can't remember ever seeing the word "חכמים" referring to anyone in such an early generation such as the generation of the Midbar.

[Related Question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36733/law-before-a-drashah-was-made)

Answer (score 1):

There is a major dispute  in the mediaeval Rabbinic authorities  about how to understand that Gemara. (see the Biur Halacha on  Oroch Chaim siman  530)  Some understand that the work on Chol Hamoed is rabbincly prohibited  with this Gemora being an asmachta. According to that they probably did work until the prohibition against it was enacted. Unless  Moshe Rabbainu himself first added this rabbinical prohibition.

Others understand it to be saying that work  on Chol Hamoed is Biblically prohibited . According to that there had to have  been some work prohibitions on Chol Hamoed .

The concept of "Lo mosron Hakosov eleh l'chachomim" (that the Torah left it up to Chazal to figure out the exact parameter) comes up elsewhere too. The Chazon Ish (Yodoyim 8:17) explains the concept in a general sense that there frequently  are  competing calculations of the correct course of action (in halachic terms "mi nidcha mpnei mi")the Torah is instructing the Rabbis to decide on the proper one. (i.e. which work prohibition would or would not have other considerations causing them (not) to be prohibited.)

Possibility   in the earlier generations, which work prohibitions  were (not) avoided  on Chol Hamoed was decided by the Rabbis of that generation depending on the situations they were facing. Afterwards there came a time when a universal Rabbinic consensus made the rules permanent and immutable.

The later authorities  bring the frequently quoted  Gemora in Yerushlmi where Rav Abba Bar Mommal said that if he could find others who agree with him he would allow some of the prohibited  work on Chol Hamoed  as an  indication that there was a POSSIBLE fluid nature of the work prohibition  on chol H'Moed at that time. Even if  a Beis Din that was bigger in number and wisdom had already prohibited that particular work prohibiton  (they don't consider this proof to be 100% conclusive)

Comment: Please [edit] and dejargonify as much as possible.  Thank you!